# Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 74735240 bytes)

Tags: laravel

i try to create a search form in my laravel project.

So i want to pass all the almost all table columns to the view so i can so i can use them to create dropboxes, checkboxes and etc.

But when i use `$var = Model::all();` it return this error:

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   74735240 bytes)

Can you advise me another solution?

This is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Lot;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $lots = Lot::all();
        return view('lots.search')->withLot($lots);
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is too much data to fit in memory. You should probably paginate your result set.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#basic-usage

```
public function index()
{
    $lots = DB::table('lots')->paginate(15);

    return view('lots.search', ['lots' => $lots]);
}
```

Or you can increase the memory limit, but that's not the best solution.

```
ini_set('memory_limit','160M');
```